# Bash edit last character in file at specified line

Tags: database, bash, file-io

I use a .txt filet as database like this:

```
is-program-installed= 0
is-program2-installed= 1
is-script3-runnig= 0
is-var5-declared= 1
```

But what if i uninstall program 2 and i want to set its database value to "0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do using `sed`:

```
sed -e '/is-program2-/ s/.$/0/' -i file.txt
```

It works like this:

- The `s/.$/0/` replaces the last character with 0: the dot matches any character, and the $ matches the end of the line--hence `.$` is the last character on the line.
- The `/is-program2-/` is a filter, so that the replacement is only executed for matching lines.

The filter pattern I used is a bit lazy: it's short but inaccurate. A longer, more strict solution would be:

```
sed -e '/^is-program2-installed= / s/.$/0/' -i file.txt
```

Comment: Now's pretty much perfect! Tank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap a `sed` command (see @janos' answer) in a function for ease of use:

Define:

```
function markuninstalled () {
    PROGRAM=${1?Usage: markuninstalled PROGRAM [FILE]}
    FILE=${2:-file.txt}

    sed -e "/^is-$PROGRAM-/ s/.$/0/" -i.bak $FILE
}
```

and then, use it like this:

```
markuninstalled program2
```

and it will modify the default file `file.txt` and create a copy.

Comment: Yes i was wandering myself how to do something similar...
Also if i don't really understand how it works..

Comment: Could you please explain it briefly? i got problems on 2° and 3° lines..
what says where and how to use the string give in recall?

Comment: Second line defines the variable PROGRAM as the first argument or displays an error message if not provided. Third line defines the variable FILE as the second argument if provided, or to the default `file.txt` if not provided. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: Ok.. So "1" means "First argument given" - "?" mean "echo error if not defined" - "Usage:" also tells that it's the first argument given and explain how it should act with others.
Right?

Comment: $1 corresponds to the first argument, $2 to the second, etc. The line 'USAGE: ...' is the error message. It is common to give a one-line explication starting with 'USAGE: ' in such cases.

Comment: Tank You really much! Everybody in this community is really helping me! You're great guys!